# sql Server: Rank by sum of points and order by ranking

Tags: sql-server

I have a game table with these fields:

```
ID    Name       Email      Points
----------------------------------
1     John     john@aaa.com    120
2     Test     bob@aaa.com     100
3     John     john@bbb.com    80
4     Bob      bob@aaa.com     50
5     John     john@aaa.com    80
```

I want to group them by email (email Identifies that both players are the same no matter that row 2 and 4 have different names) and have also sum of points and the last entered name in the results and rank them with the heighest sum of points to the lowest

the Result I want from the sample table is:

```
Ranking     Name       Points   Games_Played      Average_Points 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          John        200         2                100
 2          Bob         150         2                75
 3          John        80          1                80
```

I could achieve getting ranking, sum of points, and average points but getting the last entered name I think need joining with the same table again and it seems a little wrong.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Displaying the Name and grouping be email will cause to use e.g. MIN(Name) and lead to duplicate names.

```
Select Rank() over (order by Points desc) as Rank
,Name,Points,Games_Played,Average_Points
from
(
Select Min(Name) as Name,Email,Sum(Points) as Points
,Count(*) as Games_Played,AVG(Points) as Average_Points
From @a Group by Email
) a 
order by Rank
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16094)

in the Fiddle are two commented lines you should uncomment to see the behavior on identical results.

Comment: Fabulous Answer. Thanks..... solved my problem and learned some new things. shouldn't it be Max(name)? what Min(name) means?

Comment: I'd use email to be clearly and omit the name, it's up to you using the MINinimum or MAXimum Name, it's a kind of random in any case.

Comment: well I just want to know what is the functionality of Max or Min for the name as its not a number, does it work like dictionary ordering?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Ranking Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) from SQL-Server 2005 upwards:

```
WITH Points 
     AS (SELECT Sum_Points = Sum(points) OVER ( 
                                 partition BY email), 
                Games_Played = Count(ID) OVER ( 
                                 partition BY email), 
                Average_Points = AVG(Points) OVER ( 
                                 partition BY email), 
                Rank = DENSE_RANK()  OVER ( 
                              Partition BY email Order By Points DESC),
                * 
         FROM   dbo.Game)
SELECT Ranking=DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Sum_Points DESC), 
       Name, 
       Points=Sum_Points, 
       Games_Played,
       Average_Points
FROM   Points 
WHERE Rank = 1
Order By Sum_Points DESC;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6b31/19/0)

Note that the result is different since i'm showing the row with the highest point in case that the email is not unique, so "Test" instead of "Bob".

Answer (score 2):

Below are separate solutions for SQL Server 2012+, 2005 to 2008 R2, and 2000:

**2012+**

```
CREATE TABLE #PlayerPoints
    ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , Points INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #PlayerPoints (ID, Name, Email, Points)
VALUES
      (1, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 120)
    , (2, 'Test', 'bob@aaa.com', 100)
    , (3, 'John', 'john@bbb.com', 80)
    , (4, 'Bob', 'bob@aaa.com', 50)
    , (5, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 80)

WITH BaseData
AS
    (SELECT ID
        , Email
        , Points
        , LastRecordName = LAST_VALUE(Name) OVER
            (PARTITION BY Email
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM #PlayerPoints)
SELECT Email
    , LastRecordName = MAX(LastRecordName)
    , Points = SUM(Points)
    , Games_Played = COUNT(*)
    , Average_Points = AVG(Points)
FROM BaseData
GROUP BY Email
ORDER BY Points DESC;
```

**2005 to 2008 R2**

```
CREATE TABLE #PlayerPoints
    ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , Points INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #PlayerPoints (ID, Name, Email, Points)
VALUES
      (1, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 120)
    , (2, 'Test', 'bob@aaa.com', 100)
    , (3, 'John', 'john@bbb.com', 80)
    , (4, 'Bob', 'bob@aaa.com', 50)
    , (5, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 80)

WITH BaseData
AS
    (SELECT ID
        , Email
        , Name
        , ReverseOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY Email
            ORDER BY ID DESC)
    FROM #PlayerPoints)
SELECT pp.Email
    , LastRecordName = MAX(bd.Name)
    , Points = SUM(pp.Points)
    , Games_Played = COUNT(*)
    , Average_Points = AVG(pp.Points)
FROM #PlayerPoints pp
JOIN BaseData bd
    ON pp.Email = bd.Email
    AND bd.ReverseOrder = 1
GROUP BY pp.Email
ORDER BY Points DESC;
```

**2000**

```
CREATE TABLE #PlayerPoints
    ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , Name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , Points INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #PlayerPoints (ID, Name, Email, Points)
SELECT 1, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 120
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Test', 'bob@aaa.com', 100
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'John', 'john@bbb.com', 80
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Bob', 'bob@aaa.com', 50
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'John', 'john@aaa.com', 80;

SELECT pp.Email
    , LastRecordName = MAX(sppmi.Name)
    , Points = SUM(pp.Points)
    , Games_Played = COUNT(*)
    , Average_Points = AVG(pp.Points)
FROM #PlayerPoints pp
JOIN 
    (SELECT spp.Email
        , spp.Name
    FROM #PlayerPoints spp
    JOIN 
        (SELECT Email
            , MaximumID = MAX(ID)
        FROM #PlayerPoints
        GROUP BY Email) mi
        ON spp.ID = mi.MaximumID) sppmi
    ON pp.Email = sppmi.Email
GROUP BY pp.Email
ORDER BY Points DESC;
```

Comment: +1 . . . Yours is the only solution that handles the actual constraint on name correctly.  I do think the solution is limited, relying on a function only available in SQL Server 2012, when that is not specified in the OP.

Comment: I'll add a 2005+ solution as well.

Comment: And added a 2000 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum(r1.points) Desc) as Ranking,
    r1.name as Name,
    sum(r1.points) as Points,
    r3.gplayed as 'Games Played',
    r2.points 'Average Points'
from ranks r1
    join (select avg(points) as points, email from ranks group by email) r2 
        on r1.email = r2.email
    join (select email, count(*) as gplayed from ranks group by email) r3 
        on r1.email = r3.email
group by 
    r1.email, 
    r1.name, 
    r2.points, 
    r3.gplayed
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b2d9/26).

Answer (score 0):

Only the solution from @RegisteredUser seems to handle the constraint on the `name`.  However, it requires SQL Server 2012, so here is a more general solution:

```
      Select dense_rank() over (order by sum(points) desc) as ranking
             max(case when islastid = 1 then Name end) as Name, Email, Sum(Points) as Points, 
             Count(*) as Games_Played, AVG(Points) as Average_Points
      From (select g.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by email order by id desc) as islastid
            from games g
           ) t
      Group by Email;
```

You don't have enough information in the question to choose between `rank()` and `dense_rank()`.

Also, this version is simpler relative to other versions, because you can mix window functions and aggregation functions.