# Mssql how to select SUM with top 10 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Data example is as below

```
UserName    Score     Subject
_____________________________
James       80        DDC1
James       90        EGG2
Amy         80        OPP8
Jemmy       50        CBC5
Linko       90        DD1
Bowie       80        AZZ6
Bowie       100       GGC1
Bowie       100       EOO2
```

I would like to select the top 3 highest total score , The Output should be as follow ,

```
UserName    Score     
__________________
Bowei       280
James       170
Linko       90
```

May I know how to write this in Mssql query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql Server: Rank by sum of points and order by ranking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265181/sql-server-rank-by-sum-of-points-and-order-by-ranking)

Answer (score 5):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause to group rows by `UserName`.  The `SUM()` aggregate can be used to compute the total score per group (UserName).  Use an `ORDER BY` clause to show the largest aggregate scores first.  Lastly, `TOP` lets you select the first N results.

```
select top 3 UserName, sum(Score) as Score
from UserScores
group by UserName
order by sum(Score) desc
```

Comment: Ugh.. beat me to it by a few seconds.  Nice answer =)